# jquery string not working inside $()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jquery function. and i am calling it as below mentioned.

```
function hideSubArea(area, subArea) {
    if ($('#cmdArea').val() == area) {
        console.log('hide:' + subArea);
        //$(":checkbox[value=peoplebulkinsert]").closest("label").hide();
        $(":checkbox[value=subArea]").closest("label").hide();
    }
}
```

And calling it as

```
  hideSubArea('<?php echo CustomType::CF_PEOPLE ?>', '<?php echo CustomType::CF_SUB_PEOPLE_BULK_INSERT ?>');
```

this way its not working.

also this is not.

```
hideSubArea('people', 'peoplebulkinsert');
```

but it works when i directly use as

```
$(":checkbox[value=peoplebulkinsert]").closest("label").hide();
```

why this happens with jquery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`subArea` is a variable, not a string in this case. It needs to be concatenated. It should be -

```
$(":checkbox[value='" + subArea + "']")
```

Comment: Add quotes for value `$(":checkbox[value='" + subArea + "']")`